# Error to deploy MVC 4 to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a MVC 4 app to Azure but I am receiving this error

> Error 1  Web deployment task failed.
>   ('Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentBaseOptions' does not contain a
>   definition for 'UserAgent)

Will appreciate any help to fix it.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998027/ms-deploy-task-failed-deploymentbaseoptions-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-us

Comment: Having the same problem. I looked at the other question but Web Deploy 3.5 could not be installed...