# Unable to deploy my Azure Web App using visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, sharepoint-online

I have Visual Studio 2019 and i followed the steps mentioned in this link https://www.tatvasoft.com.au/blog/how-to-implement-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-online/ to create a remote event receiver inside our SharePoint online development site.

But when i try to publish the remote event receiver inside visual studio, i got this error:-

> Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line
>   Suppression State Error        Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy
>   experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate
>   the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem
>   persists.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)
>   SharePointAddIn3Web

Here is a screen shot from VS:-

[image]

Here is the diagnostic log error:-

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__213.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

===================
```

Can anyone advice why i am getting this error?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Since my above development server has zscaler installed, so I moved the project to another development server which does not have zscaler and when i try to publish i got this error now

> "MS Deploy task failed DeploymentBaseOptions does not contain a
>   definition for UserAgent".

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58573665/184220 it relates to your edit

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when there is no connectivity (Low speed internet) or if you are running any tools parallelly which uses your network.

Can you stop if you are running any tool such as fiddler. Follow the [`solution`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2015/09/14/error_connection_terminated-msdeploy-web-deploy/) here.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the internet speed is fast and i am not using fiddler

Comment: are you using resharper? what is the appservice plan?

Comment: thanks again for the reply, the azure app service plan is "ASP-n1-a5b4 (S1: 1)"

Comment: can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311166/can-not-publish-since-moving-to-vs-2019 or create new profile and see

Comment: thanks for the link but i am not sure where i need to add this `<UseMSDeployExe>True</UseMSDeployExe>
<AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>`

Comment: also the error inside this link @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311166/can-not-publish-since-moving-to-vs-2019 is different than my error

Comment: could you try creating a new profile and see? it could be due to memory error as well

Comment: i already tried creating new app service inside azure but did not fix the issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205352/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-test-test).

Comment: Try to install Web Deploy 3.5 (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy). and see

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me, it was because the ProjectName length. 
On "Output" window in VS i was able to see,

"Unable to copy file "System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll" to "System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
"
it is a common error that happens for windows.
then i moved the folder to "D" drive to solve it.

you should look at the Output window in Visual studio. whats the last error it gives.